# How to generate a mesh between 2 random points using pathfinding and avoiding obstacles in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bezier, smoothing

I'm trying to create curves along a path. I've used A* (Sebastian Lague's tutorials) to get the shortest path between 2 random points. 
After that, I split the path in segments (based on the direction of the nodes). 
Once that's finished I make some (cubic) bezier curves between the begin and endpoints in the current segment. 
Some of the angles between the curves are not really smooth though.

Does anyone know how I make smooth curves that keep obstacle avoidance in consideration, and generate a mesh over it?

This is what I have as of now: I instantiated cubes (with a different color for each segment) along the path. The green lines are my curves. See photo:

[image: My current progress]

---

Comment: ...And your code?

Comment: Do you need to roll your own? Unity comes with mesh navigation built in, is that not sufficient for what you need to do? (Because presumably you want decent path planning. "I want my code to work" is not a goal in and of itself)